# Replace Linux with Windows via SSH

Tags: linux, windows, ssh

Is there a way to replace Linux with a Microsoft Server, only by using a shell?

I know that there a "easy" ways to install Windows in a virtual maschine, and simply boot form that, but that is not what i need. I need to completely replace the linux.

I have already created an unattended boot disk, and tested it on a vm, it works fine without the need that i type something in, but how can i accomplish it that the server will boot the setup when i restart it?

Comment: For someone to be able to produce an answer to this, some additional information might be useful: For example, what kind of remote system are we talking about, it is a virtual machine, but is it a KVM, Xen, VMware, what? Do you have access to the console of the virtual machine? How have you planned to access the system after Windows has been installed (Windows hints at that there are more than just SSH open anyway, so there might be other ways of accomplishing what you'd like to do)?

Comment: Thans for your comment. Well, it should work on "every maschine". There are sites offering such an OS switch for about $50, and they seems to be able to do that on every server. The most used options are (in my oppinion) OpenVZ, KVM, and a dedicated server. Accessing the system is no problem, as i said, i created a unattended installaiton which also set's up the firewall and everything else fully automatically. It "just" needs to start the installation file. But that's the thing i am not able to accomplish. Any help is therefore greatly appreciated. Thank you very much.